# How to store actions such as like, create, etc. by a user on Yammer?

Tags: office365, yammer

I am creating an app with `Yammer` and I want store actions done on `Yammer` such as like and create from a user and use it to reward the user. Is there any API or SDK from `Yammer` which helps me achieve this? I did all the research but still couldn't find anything.

My application is based on JavaScript.

Please provide your answers with exact links if possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your application is supposed to do? You can post messages for example with the REST API using the Yammer JS SDK.

Comment: I want to record that activity that some user posted a message. I want to store that event in the database not the message just the post event. I want to store that event so that i can award the user some batches on the activities the user has done. @BrianLyttle